# If 52 cards are arranged randomly.. what is the probability of card (J, K or Q) if a card is taken in game.

Tags: probability

Help needed with following probability question

If 52 cards are arranged randomly.. what is the probability of card (J, K or Q) if a card is taken in game.

thankyou

Comment: hint: look only at tthe card you have drawn.

Comment: is it 12/52 the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: How many total J,K,Q are there? How many cards altogether? So what is the probability?

Comment: 12/52 is the answer ? right ?

Comment: Yes! That's correct.